# Load jar file with URLCLassLoader

Tags: java, reflection, jar, bungeecord

I am trying to load a jar file as if it was run with "java -jar BungeeCord.jar", but I am trying to do this from within another jar. I can not use a process builder because I need get an instance of classes uses in the external jar file.

I have created this:

```
System.out.println("Loading jar: " + jar.toURI().toURL());

    child = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{jar.toURI().toURL()}, BungeeServer.class.getClassLoader());

    Class<?> classToLoad = Class.forName("net.md_5.bungee.Bootstrap", true, child);
    final Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);

    new Thread(new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            try {
                method.invoke(null, (Object) new String[]{});
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                BungeeControl.shutdown();
            }
        }

    }).start();
```

This starts up the jar file, but it gets the following error about a dozen times on start which don't occur if I start the same file normally:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/md_5/bungee/api/plugin/Plugin
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader.loadClass0(PluginClassloader.java:34)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader.loadClass(PluginClassloader.java:27)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginManager.enablePlugin(PluginManager.java:304)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginManager.loadPlugins(PluginManager.java:212)
    at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord.start(BungeeCord.java:264)
    at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCordLauncher.main(BungeeCordLauncher.java:55)
    at net.md_5.bungee.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.moltrespvp.bungeecontrol.BungeeServer$1.run(BungeeServer.java:31)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.Plugin
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader.loadClass0(PluginClassloader.java:53)
    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginClassloader.loadClass(PluginClassloader.java:27)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

If needed, here is the manifest for Bungeecord:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Version: git:BungeeCord-Bootstrap:1.12-SNAPSHOT:16d2615
 :1233
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: jenkins
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.5
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_121
Specification-Version: 20170514
Main-Class: net.md_5.bungee.Bootstrap
```

How can I start this jar file as if I started it with a ProcessBuilder, but be able to access methods from the running instance.

For example, I need to be able to run this for the running instance of BungeeCord `ProxyServer.getInstance()`?

Comment: Does that jar depend on any other jars? To reflect into a jar, you need to load the jars in that jar's classpath. (Not sure if I worded that right). For example if that jar has a class that uses Gson(), you need to also provide your URLClassLoader the URL for the gson jar

Comment: If it does, it is all inside BungeeCore.jar? Does that matter then?

Comment: You're saying the BungeeCore.jar, ie the jar you're trying to run the other jar from, has the same jars in its own classpath?

Comment: No. I mean it has other things like jline and other libraries, but they are all compiled as .class files.

Comment: So the libraries it depends on are extracted and packaged in the jar itself? If that's true, then you only need to include the jar's url.

Comment: Actually to be safe, do this: `child2 = (URLCLassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` which have all the default URLS for the jar you're working in. create a new `URL[]` with all those URLS and also add the URL of your jar. See if this `URL[]` has different `URL`s than the URLS your current loader has